# Vector potential for an inhomogeneous magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential

I know that you can obtain the magnetic field vector via $\vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A}$, i.e.:
$$B_x = \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial z} \\
B_y = \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial x} \\
B_z = \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial y} $$

I wish to find the vector potential $\vec{A}$ that gives rise to a non-homogeneous magnetic field such as the one in a Stern-Gerlach experiment.

A magnetic field such as $\vec{B} = \lambda z\hat{z}$ is the simplest one which would do the trick for me. However, the simplest form of $\vec{B}$ doesn't corresponds to the simplest $\vec{A}$. If I plug in $B_z = \lambda z$, $B_x = B_y = 0$ in the above equations, I get a system which is honestly too hard for me to solve (although I don't doubt it has an analytical solution, and I will accept it as answer).

Is there a "simpler" vector potential (for example, one in which at least one of the components is zero) that gives rise to a non-homogeneous $\vec{B}$?

Comment: $\nabla \cdot (\lambda z \mathbf{\hat{z}}) = \lambda \neq 0$, so it cannot be written as just the rotational of something. There are simpler examples of non-homogenous magnetic fields, say in magnetostatics, for instance, the field produced by an infinite straight line of current.

Comment: Oh wow, that was a major oversight on my part. Thanks for pointing it out.